# removing elements in one vector from another in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am having trouble finding a way to remove all of the elements of one vector from another.  I have a vector of dates called "dates", and want to remove the dates that are weekends (which are in the vector "weekends".

The code below works, but I know there must be a more efficient way to do it rather than one at a time... Let me know!

```
  for (index in 1:length(weekends)) {
    datesReformatted <- datesReformatted[datesReformatted != weekends[index]]
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
  setdiff(dates, weekends)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or this

```
days <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
weekend <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")

days[!days %in% weekend]
```