# very simple subset selection in r

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove rows of a matrix by row name, rather than numerical index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576138/how-to-remove-rows-of-a-matrix-by-row-name-rather-than-numerical-index)
>   [removing elements in one vector from another in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841511/removing-elements-in-one-vector-from-another-in-r)

I have two vectors:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b<-c(7,3,6,4,8,1)
```

I would like to select those elements of a which are not in b

I tried subset(a, a!=b) but I get the warning:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 7):

Try `setdiff` for vectors:

```
R> setdiff(a,b)
[1] 2 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a[!(a%in%b)]
```

Look at `?"%in%"`.